# Returning the custom validation method parameter in error message

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a created a custom validation function along with a custom error message for it. How can I show the value "1000" in my error message?

```
  // in my request file
  function rules() 
  {
    return [
        'my_field' => 'myValidator:1000',
    ];    
  }

  // in my custom validator file
  public function validateMyValidator($attribute, $value, $parameters)
  {
      return true;
  }

  // in resources/lang/eng/validation.php
  'custom' => [
    'my_field' => [
        'my_validator' => 'Value must be 1000',
    ],
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your own replace Function.

Let's take an existing example from the Laravel built in \Illuminate\Validation\Validator:

```
protected function replaceSame($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return str_replace(':other', $this->getAttribute($parameters[0]), $message);
}
```

The corresponding language line in validation.php is:

```
 'same' => 'The :attribute and :other must match.'
```

So in fact you have to create a function like:

```
function replace{$yourRuleName}($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
     return str_replace()... 
}
```

That replaces your own custom parameters in your validation language file.

### Other approach with Laravel 5.1

This is, how I do that kind of stuff. It's possibly not a perfect validation rule, but just to give some example.

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('olderThan', function($attribute, $value, $parameters ) {
        $minAge = ( ! empty($parameters)) ? (int) $parameters[0] : 13;

        try {
            return \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff(new \Carbon\Carbon($value))->y >= $minAge;
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    Validator::replacer('olderThan', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace(":value", $parameters[0], $message);
    });
}
```

You can extend the Validator within a ServiceProviders' boot() method. (Ideally you would create an own ValidationServiceProvider)

The corresponding language line would be:

```
"older_than" => "Minimum age is :value years",
```

Comment: Thank you shock_gone_wild! That worked, could you clarify where exactly should I place this method.

Comment: which one do you mean? The boot() function or the first one ?

Comment: Oh nevermind got it you said to make a service provider

Answer (score 0):

You should use the field name under validation as your place-holder. So here it should be:

```
'my_validator' => 'Value must be :myValidator'
```

Comment: have you tried this? I don't think this works without defining a custom replacer